# jQuery - allow to change only some part of the text in textarea

Tags: jquery

For example I have a textarea with a text.

```
<textarea id="response" name="response" class="form-control" maxlength="160">Text1. Text2</textarea>
```

I need to allow user to edit only `Text1`. `Text2` should not be changed.

Comment: You could try detecting when a user changes the text (`input` event), and then append `Text2`. However you will need to slice the string and see if the last part is `Text2`. If it is, don't append the text.

Comment: What is a user change Text2 to Textss22. So I will append Text2? So I will get Text1. Textss22. Text2

Comment: Mmmm...... I did not think of that. Why do you need `Text2` on the end? Depending on your needs, you could create another `textarea` that has `display: none`, and add Text2 to that. Then you can join the text the user types in with Text2, and use that string. They cannot edit Text2 since the textarea is hidden.

Comment: Why not only have a control for the editable content? You can append the static data when the input is used for processing.

Answer (score 0):

You cam make text1 as fixed and can edit text2 but you have to take text1 as span you can see example [HERE](http://jsbin.com/tolifa/1/watch?html,css,output)

It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off trying to create a fake textarea using CSS and the `contenteditable` tag and extracting the data from it when the form is submitted (assuming it is). Here's an example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #custom-textarea {
            border: solid 1px #999999;
            resize: both;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        #custom-textarea *:read-write:focus {
            outline: none;
        }

        #custom-textarea span {
            pointer-events: none;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#custom-textarea span").on("focus", function(){
                $(this).parent().trigger("focus");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 165px;">
        <div id="custom-textarea" tabindex="-1">
            <span contenteditable="true">This section is editable.</span>
            This section is not editable.
        </div>
    </div>
    <textarea>This section is editable. This section is still editable.</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```